# Why does the nav element wrap around the tag above it

Tags: html, css

When I place my `<nav>` inside my `<header>` the element seems to wrap the `<p></p>` above it.

http://jsfiddle.net/otherDewi/u2xNN/

**HTML**

```
<header class="clearfix">
        <h1 id="heading">Main Heading</h1>
        <h2>Sub Heading</h2>
        <p>Tagline - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Dolore, corporis.</p>

    <div id="home" class="landing">     

    </div><!--end #home-->
    <nav class="clearfix main-nav">
        <ul class="clearfix">
            <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#video">Video</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>     
</header>
```

**CSS**

```
header {
    text-align: right;
}

header p {
    float: right;
}

.main-nav {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #d3eafc;
}

.main-nav ul {
    clear: both;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 10px 0;
}

.main-nav ul li {
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    width: 150px;
    border-right: 1px solid #999;
}

.main-nav a:link,
.main-nav a:visited {
    display: block;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: I agree, I do not see an errors that jump out at me.  From the classes you have on here, is this a bootstrap or Drupal implementation?

Comment: This is a straight html, css implementation. Same error in IE, FF and Chrome

Comment: Alright, I was able to figure it out. I didn't see the problem at first.

Comment: Is there any other JavaScript libraries that could possibly be wrapping the nav inside a <p> tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it..

This was occurring because the `nav` bar was collapsing due to the fact that it didn't have a height set on it and because `<p>` was being floated.

You have 2 options, either add an `overflow`, or float the `nav` along side the `<p>`

```
.main-nav {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

or..

```
.main-nav {
    float: right;
}
```

[**Updated jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/u2xNN/1/)

Comment: Should the clear fix not stop the nav collapsing? Ahh mixing floating and non floating elements - cheers.

Comment: @otherDewi A clearfix would have works, but it just wasn't being applied to the `<p>` tagline.. Adding an overflow is also considered to be a clearfix hack.